# Merge BigQuery structs of different types/lengths

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm looking for a BigQuery equivalent to Presto's [map_concat](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/map.html#map_concat) function.

I have structs from two different tables with different types and lengths that I'd like to merge. There are no duplicates in the structs. So far, I've tried to convert the structs to JSON and merge them via a JS UDF:

```
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION CONCAT_STRUCTS(x STRING, y STRING)
RETURNS STRUCT<>
LANGUAGE js AS """
  var x = JSON.parse(x);
  var y = JSON.parse(y);
  return JSON.stringify({...x, ...y});
""";
SELECT
  a.user_id,
  CONCAT_STRUCTS(
      TO_JSON_STRING(a.features),
      TO_JSON_STRING(b.features)
  ) as features
FROM
  a
INNER JOIN
  b
ON
  a.user_id = b.user_id
```

However, this feels pretty unnatural and doesn't work since BigQuery doesn't allow an empty type to be returned for structs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have structs ... that I'd like to merge. There are no duplicates in the structs

Below "trick" is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT user_id,
  (SELECT AS STRUCT * FROM UNNEST([a.features]), UNNEST([b.features])) AS features
FROM `project.dataset.tableA` a
INNER JOIN `project.dataset.tableB` b
USING(user_id)
```

you can check this with sample data like in below example

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.tableA` AS (
  SELECT 1 user_id, STRUCT(1 AS x, 2 AS y, 3 AS z) features
), `project.dataset.tableB` AS (
  SELECT 1 user_id, STRUCT(1 AS c, 2 AS d) features
)
SELECT user_id,
  (SELECT AS STRUCT * FROM UNNEST([a.features]), UNNEST([b.features])) AS features
FROM `project.dataset.tableA` a
INNER JOIN `project.dataset.tableB` b
USING(user_id)
```

with result of two structs concatenated into one

```
Row user_id features.x  features.y  features.z  features.c  features.d   
1   1       1           2           3           1           2
```

Comment: I was not aware you could cast a struct as an array like that, worked perfectly. Great "trick" indeed. Thank you!